# JSF2 - reset ViewScopedBeans when Navigating to other page/tab

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, liferay, portlet

I'm working with a Liferay portlet with JSF2 and Primefaces.

A lot of my Backing Beans are SessionScoped, as they are keeping info needed from multiple pages of the same portlet,  and I want them to keep this info for the whole session, so I can't turn them to ViewScoped.

This way, the user has to log-out and log-in to reset the Backing Beans, and this is the supposed behavior I wanted. But I'd like to reset them when the user navigates to another portal page. So, my question is, what is the most convenient way to do this ?

1. Is there some Event I could catch when changing the page, and call some custom reset function on the Portlet?
2. Maybe some default setting on the portlet that will automatically reset the beans (no custom reset functions) ?
3. Any other Ideas ?

thanx!

Comment: @Xtreme Biker: thanx for adding the Liferay and Portlet tags, they were really needed.